# TypeScript With Asp.net WebSite in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, web, typescript

I have installed TypeScript plugin for VS2012 and  could able to add a TypeScript file(.ts) to Asp.Net Web Application project and after making some modification to csproj it is generating .js(Javascript) file on build and is running perfectly.Now what i need is, to add A TypeScript file to Asp.Net Website Project,since the template is not available i added a .js file and renamed to .ts file and  wrote TypeScript code there,but on build it is not generating corresponding .js file.So now the question is ,how to use TypeScript with Asp.Net Website in VS2012

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to install the Visual Studio 2012 plugin, as detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timart/archive/2012/10/02/typescript-project-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx). It appears different versions of VS require their own plugins.